# how to work with laravel modal using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

Iam working on a simple laravel project where i have a page with http://loocalhost:8000/home as url .i have a button on the page.clicking the button will open a modal where i will have a form.What my problem is whenever i submit the form in the modal the data should be saved in database .i want to implement it by using ajax and then pass it to controller.but i don't know how to implement it exactly.

my modal in

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New post</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="frmPost" name="frmPost" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">
            <div class="form-group error">
             <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title</label>
               <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="">
               </div>
               </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="inputDetail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="">Add</button>
        <!-- <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="0"> -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my home page with url :http://localhost:8000/home

```
  <button id="btn_add" name="btn_add" class="btn btn-default">New Post</button>
```

my ajax code :

```
   $('#btn_add').click(function(){
           var url = "http://localhost:8080/home";
            $('#btn-save').val("add");
            $('#frmPost').trigger("reset");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#btn-save').click(function(e){

                $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token()"]').attr('content')
                        }

                })

                var formData = {
                        'title':$('#title').val(),
                        'description' :$('#description').val()
                    }


                $.ajax({ //line 28
                        url: url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { userData: formData },
                        success: function()
                        {
                            alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
                        }
                });

            });
        });
```

routes.php code:

```
  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');//route for home page after login
  Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@addPost');//route to go after submitting modal data.
```

But i am getting error i dont know what the issue.can someone help me?
My error:
jquery.js?27d9:9536 POST http://localhost:8080/home net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Is it really port `8080` (different app) or you just mistype it? Because you said at the beginning of your post you use port `8000`. If you really use port `8080` for ajax then make sure it is listening.

Comment: yeah its 8000 only

Comment: then change this line `var url = "http://localhost:8080/home";`

Comment: yeah i changed it ,bow iam getting internal server error 500

Comment: Well, that's an another problem. You just hit that link with POST, `type: 'POST',`. While on your `routes.php`, there are only `Route::get`. You might want to change that to `Route::post`, for the `addPost` one I assumed.

Comment: sorry for that i have changed it already with post method but not changed in my question.still iam getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127422/discussion-between-user3860618-and-escepta).